# Adding custom CSS classes to different HTML elements output by Wordpress/Genesis

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm working on integrating the Gridiculous grid with the Genesis Framework. Genesis already has some nice responsiveness built in, but I'd like to be able to quickly adjust my layout and get the nice fluidity that Gridiculous offers.

To do that, I'd like to be able to add custom classes to the major layout elements such as content, and sidebar. So, I'd like to be able to add a CSS class of .c3, .c8 etc to specific HTML elements. I need to be able to take

```
<div class="primary-sidebar">
```

and make it so that it's

```
<div class="primary-sidebar c3">
```

Am I barking up the wrong tree here? What path would be best to take to add specific classes like this to different elements? Body classes and post classes won't really work for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question, I think you're definitely on the right track. You will have to write those multiple classes, of course, on your own so that the applied properties can take place. I would say start with whatever the Gridiculous supplies you in the CSS, and then add any additional styling in your own stylesheet.

In short, you would have to include the `primary-sidebar c3` class in some stylesheet, but you can just copy the `primary-sidebar` properties given, and add your own customization to them. Hope that helps!